# Python: search for words in a text file and print line with line number

Tags: python, parsing, input, grep

**My goal is to create a script that search for credentials in an input file.**

I find endless example, *even here on StackOverflow*, that can teach me how to search for a range of words in a file:

- [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691954/how-can-i-search-a-text-file-of-list-of-words-from-user-input-and-print-the-line)
- [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749125/searching-a-text-file-and-printing-line-numbers)

By the way, when I try to apply those rules to my script it return me nothing.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                              
parser.add_argument('-input', dest='input',help="input one or more files",metavar=None)                     
args = parser.parse_args()


GrabdirectoryFile = open(args.input,"r",encoding='UTF8')                    
directoryFile = GrabdirectoryFile.read()

HotWords = ['password', 'admin']

def search_for_lines(filename, words_list):
    words_found = 0
    for line_no, line in enumerate(filename):
        if any(word in line for word in words_list):
            print(line_no, ':', line)
            words_found += 1
    return words_found

search_for_lines(directoryFile,HotWords)
```

I tried following the instructions I find on the 2 links provided above but no luck.

[image]

The code is definitely executed and `Python` returns no errors.
The file contains many words and also a few 'password' and 'admin' but no line is returned.

Why?

**EDIT:**

dear @Kirk Broadhurst, @SIM, @André Schild, @kasperhj, @Garrett Hyde, I tried to follow your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366554/how-to-search-for-word-in-text-file-and-print-part-of-line-with-python) and and substitute my code with:

```
with open(args.input) as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if "color=" in part:
                print (part)
```

but unfortunately is still not working. The right solution was provided here below by @Farhan.K, I had to use readlines() instead of read()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the file using `file.read()` which returns a string but you are expecting a list. Use `file.readlines()` instead. As an aside, it is better use open/close files using the `with` statement.

Replace

```
GrabdirectoryFile = open(args.input,"r",encoding='UTF8')                    
directoryFile = GrabdirectoryFile.read()
```

with...

```
GrabdirectoryFile = open(args.input,"r",encoding='UTF8')                    
directoryFile = GrabdirectoryFile.readlines()
```

Using a `with` statement is better:

```
with open(args.input,"r",encoding='UTF8') as GrabdirectoryFile:
    directoryFile = GrabdirectoryFile.readlines()
```